# Reference a line/item from a recurring section/table in another recurring section/table

Tags: cognito-forms

I am looking to build a form that asks a customer for a list of items (in this case locations and their website) on page 1, and on page 2 I want some elaboration on the specfics for the website.

I am trying to capture the domain field from my table as a calculated value in the 2nd recurring section or table. 
However I can only get all entries or none. 
What i'd like is this:

table 1:

```
entry 1: location|variable|variable|website
entry 2: location|variable|variable|website
etc.
```

table 2:

```
entry 1: (calc)location from table1.entry1|(calc)website from table1.entry1|variable|variable
entry 2: (calc)location from table1.entry2|(calc)website from table1.entry2|variable|variable
etc.
```

I have tried the following:

```
=Form.SECTION1.TABLE1.Where(ItemNumber = Form.SECTION2.TABLE2.ItemNumber).Select(Website)
```

(basically I am trying to dynamically generate the ItemNumber = 1, 2, 3, etc. by equating this to the current ItemNumber in the table)

If this would work with recurring sections I'd be just as happy.

is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm a developer with Cognito Forms. We would be able to better see what you are trying to set up and do if you could submit a Support Request (https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/). This would let us review your form and offer help with what you are looking to do.